# Fractional values differs for various resolution - CSS - Google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using 1920 X 1080 resolution with 100% and the height and width of my div renders as below,
[Image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTzS6.png)

height **15.625** and width will be **16.469**

While am taking a new machine 3840 X 2160 resolution with 200% (which some what equivalent with 1920 X 1080 resolution with 100%) but here the height might be **15.631** and width will be **16.477**

Whether chrome decides the fractional part based on resolution ? if so both are same resolutions at my case.
No issues with Firefox

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give more details like 100% of what parent container? Like the actual snippet or a repro with jsfiddle?

Comment: @PankajParashar 100% 200% is the resolution percentage on the display settings